# Can a DataContractSerializer be setup to ignore errors in a file rather then just fail entirely?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontractserializer, backwards-compatibility

I'm using DataContractSerializer to save a large number of different classes which make up a tree structures to XML files. I'm in the initial stages of writing this software so at this point all the different components are changing around quite a bit. Yet every time I make a change to a class I end up breaking my programs ability to open previously saved files.

My tree structures will still be functional if components are missing. Is there some way to tell DataContractSerializer to skip over data it has a problem deserializing and continue on rather then just quitting at the first problem it has?

I know one answer would be to write my own serialization class, but I'd rather not spend the time to do that. I was hopping to still be able to take advantage of DataContractSerializer, but with out it being an all or nothing situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is IExtensibleDataObject. This way, any unexpected elements get read into a name-value dictionary maintained internally, and can even be serialized back later. See the following resources for help.

[Blog post -- WCF Extensibility – Other Serialization Extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/09/27/wcf-extensibility-other-serialization-extensions.aspx)

[Forward-Compatible Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731083.aspx)

[Data Contract Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731138.aspx)

Comment: Same issue here. It was a good idea, I tried IExtensibleDataObject, but it doesn't seem to work. Probably depends on the serializer, mine is json and it might be totally ignoring this.